# Safety of nested hashes

Tags: hash, sha-256

Assume that you use this function: `SHA-256(key_1 + SHA-256(key_2 + SHA-256(key_3 + special_key)))`. First, second and third keys are long random strings of 64 bytes. A special key is a short string (from 5 to 12 bytes).
Also, assume that an attacker has:

- the special key;
- 16 bytes from the beginning of the function result.

How realistic is it for an attacker to obtain the keys 1, 2 and 3? Is there any vulnerability, except brute force? And if the attacker has multiple pairs of key/result string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to HMAC-SHA-256 with 64-byte key, except that

- HMAC-SHA-256 has two SHA-256 layers where there is three;
- HMAC derives its two `key_j` from a single one (using XOR with constants) rather than using independent keys;
- HMAC potentially reveals its whole 32-byte output, rather than part of it;
- HMAC's security model  includes the adversary choosing the messages (that is, values of `special_key`) for which it obtains input; and seeking something weaker than key recovery (ability to distinguish the function from random).

It follows this is at least as strong as HMAC-SHA-256 is: with a strong theoretical argument even for relatively weak hypothesis on SHA-256 (the [generic proof of HMAC](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/hmac-new.html) applies), and unbroken.

Key leak by some side channels might still be an issue for a particular implementation, though.